# How to decode char from wchar_t

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

I have an encoded wstring. because wchar_t is 16bit wide we have encoded 2 chars to it.

```
wstring e_str = L"A B C \uffff";
....
wstring temp;
....
wchar_t value = e_str[i]; /* e_str = encoded wstring */
....
if (value > L'\u00ff) {
    temp.append(1,(character-(character % 256))/256);
    temp.append(1,character % 256);
}
```

after encoding it becomes `"A B C \uÿÿ"`.

What i want to do is get the original string back (e_str).

Comment: you mean "2 chars back"?

Comment: When does it "become 'A B C \uÿÿ"? When you printf() it? What is the corresponding code?

Comment: e_str is 7 charactes long. You can't expect to get the original string back if you use append 2 times for the last characters. each append call will add a new wchar_t to temp. Explain what you are trying to do, please

Comment: I think you need to learn more about encodings in general before attempting this. Different characters have different representations in different encodings. It's not usually as straightforward as you believe it to be.

Comment: The modulus operation in `(character-(character % 256))/256)` does nothing useful. Can you explain what you hoped to achieve with that line?

Comment: "What i want to do is get the original string back" -- that is impossible. The original string contains a wchar value that cannot be represented in a char.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
char loChar=(char)(value);
char hiChar=(char)(value>>8);
```